# Python multithreading: spawning multiple threads, only last one executed

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to write a very basic simulator where clients are arriving at random arrival times and then stay for a random amount of time and then leave again.

The idea is that every time a client is generated, a seperate thread is spawned where the client is deleted after a random amount of time (see delete_user() function).

```
def delete_user(user):
    time.sleep(random.randint(5,20))
    print "User %s left at %s" % (user.id, time.ctime())

def start_simulation(number_users, interval):
    for i in range(number_users):
        t = random.expovariate(1.0 / interval)
        time.sleep(t) # wait random time before generating a new user
        user = generate_user()
        print "User %s generated at %s" % (user.id, time.ctime())
        worker = threading.Thread(target=delete_user, args=(user,))
        worker.start()
```

The problem is that the delete_user() is only executed once, for the last user that is generated. It seems as though only the last spawned thread actually does something.

This is the output:

```
User b490fbd0-8740-4d7e-a3a6-d46449ff918b generated at Wed Apr  1 07:22:47 2015
User 844122d9-4032-4866-9e07-eb86f076a531 generated at Wed Apr  1 07:22:49 2015
User 91e238fc-4ed1-4a81-a434-9a50d3b01fed generated at Wed Apr  1 07:22:52 2015
User 877c8e3f-2b3d-4997-9644-98d078388427 generated at Wed Apr  1 07:22:52 2015
User a77dcefc-8ea1-467d-8365-923b789ab4bb generated at Wed Apr  1 07:22:54 2015
User a77dcefc-8ea1-467d-8365-923b789ab4bb left at Wed Apr  1 07:23:02 2015
```

Am I overlooking something? Or is there an easier way to achieve the same functionality I need?

Thanks

Comment: Can you not just randomly draw the start time and the length of time they are present and then have a loop over time, which will perform any actions that occur at that time?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to do something like that. But what do you mean exactly with 'loop over time'? Do you mean that I should e.g. sleep a second, wake up, check if an event should be done and then sleep for a second again?

Comment: That would be one way to do it (and certainly what i was thinking of), but a quick google has turned up this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html, which i think does pretty much what you want

Comment: Thanks, that should indeed do what I want!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Moved from comment section:

A quick google has turned up this: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html, which I think does pretty much what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure you can't define multiple threads with the same variable name over and over. Every time you redefine it you are canceling the last thread, and the threads run anywhere from 5 - 20 seconds, and of course your for loop doesn't wait that long to create a new thread. Maybe you should try something like the [`Scheduling`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) module.

The *"Evil"* alternative, with the exception that you cant call Thread.cancel():

`exec(str(random.random) + ' = threading.Thread(target=delete_user, args=(user,))'`